# How to delete items from a listbox on Windows 7 phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I use ItemsSource, when I want to delete an item from my list I get an error.
Error:
Operation not supported on read-only collection.

```
        MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) sender;
        MessageBox.Show(menuItem.Header.ToString(), "Result", MessageBoxButton.OK);

        ListBoxItem lb (ListBoxItem)listBoxJournal.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(((MenuItem)sender).DataContext);

        liste.Remove((Note)lb.Content);
        listBoxJournal.UpdateLayout();
        listBoxJournal.Items.Clear();
        listBoxJournal.ItemsSource = liste;
```

I get the error on the line items.clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you set ItemsSource on the ListBox, then Items is internally generated and read-only. 
So in this case you need to delete the item from the supoplied item collection. 
If the collection implements INotifyCollectionChanged, then the collection changes are reflected in the listbox.

ObservableCollection is a list that implemented INotifyCollectionChanged

Answer (score 4):

use that --- Listname.RemoveAt(ListBoxName.SelectedIndex);